# How to get error body returned by server when using Retrofit + Coroutine

Tags: android, exception, error-handling, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

When using Coroutine with Retrofit in order to call network apis, in case the server returns an error (response code != 200) we will get an Exception. My question is how to find/read the error body (in Json) sent by the server through the Exception?

```
try{
     apiService.login()
}catch(exception:Exception){
     //How to read error body from exception
     //Error body example: {"ok":false,"error":"Incorrect username or password."}
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will just need to do this:

```
(exception as? HttpException)?.response()?.errorBody()?.string()
```

This will return the error body in Json format.

Answer (score 1):

For handling the error with coroutine and retrofit you have to create a Sealed class, follow the steps...

1: StateHandle Class

```
sealed class NetworkState {
  data class Success(val data : CharactersResponseModel) : NetworkState()
  object InvalidData : NetworkState()
  data class Error(val error : String) : NetworkState()
  data class NetworkException(val error : String) : NetworkState()
  sealed class HttpErrors : NetworkState() {
    data class ResourceForbidden(val exception: String) : HttpErrors()
    data class ResourceNotFound(val exception: String) : HttpErrors()
    data class InternalServerError(val exception: String) : HttpErrors()
    data class BadGateWay(val exception: String) : HttpErrors()
    data class ResourceRemoved(val exception: String) : HttpErrors()
    data class RemovedResourceFound(val exception: String) : HttpErrors()
  }
}
```

2. Handle error or success API call

   ```
    private suspend fun fetchCharacters() : NetworkState {
    return try {
      val response = apiService.getCharacters()
      if (response.isSuccessful) {
        if (response != null) {
          NetworkState.Success(response.body()!!)
        } else {
          NetworkState.InvalidData
        }
      } else {
        when(response.code()) {
          403 -> NetworkState.HttpErrors.ResourceForbidden(response.message())
          404 -> NetworkState.HttpErrors.ResourceNotFound(response.message())
          500 -> NetworkState.HttpErrors.InternalServerError(response.message())
          502 -> NetworkState.HttpErrors.BadGateWay(response.message())
          301 -> NetworkState.HttpErrors.ResourceRemoved(response.message())
          302 -> NetworkState.HttpErrors.RemovedResourceFound(response.message())
          else -> NetworkState.Error(response.message())
        }
      }

    } catch (error : IOException) {
      NetworkState.NetworkException(error.message!!)
    }
   ```

   }
3. Make liveData or flow to Observer the neworkState in your UI